# getting exception error whiule doing xslt transformation through xalan in java

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I am transforming an xml to generate a new xml by parsing it through xslt bit while doing transformation through xalan api.. now below i am doing the transformation

```
  String mess = "C:\\wer\\erty.xml";
    mess = mess.trim().replaceFirst("^([\\W]+)<","<");

        // perform XSL transformation
                xsltTransformer.transform(msgStreamSource, xmlOutput);
```

I am getting the below error ..

```
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in prolog.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete code to allow us to reproduce the problem. You have posted two lines of code manipulating a `mess` variable which is a string and a third line which does not even use that variable. So we have no way of telling what you are doing. How does the XML you want to transform look like exactly?

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog" means that there's a problem with an XML file, and it was detected right at the beginning of the file. It might be the file is empty, or starts with a blank line, or is in the wrong encoding, other other similar problems.